# Send REST response to Handlebars to parse JSON

Tags: rest, express, handlebars.js

So i've recently took the jump to node based web apps (I've been playing around with a lot a lot but now I'm actually creating something)

So i've set up a simple REST API using Express, MongoDB and Node (published on Heroku)
Now I am trying to create a client/web app also in Express and Node that communicates with the API and parses the responses and actually views the object.

What I want to do is list the current entries of the API on a simple page.
So i've created a route to '/home' in my app that works fine.
It uses a handlebars template that works fine too.

I use a 'home.js' file to render the view like so:

```
var request = require('request');   
exports.index = function (req, res) {
   res.render('home', {
       title: 'home'
   });
};
```

I've tried different things here but whenever I do something like:

```
var request = require('request');

exports.index = function (req, res) {
   res.render('home', {
       title: 'home',
       items: getItems
   });
};

var getItems = function(req, res, next) {
    request(process.env.API_URL, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
           return body;
        }
    }
};
```

It returns the `request` object/function instead of the body (which I can parse in handlebars :P)

I did numerous variations on this call (calling it within the `exporst.index` functions, outside of it, creating a options variable and a seperate callback like `request(options, callback)`) but they all either error or return the `request` object/function.

When I do `console.log(body);` instead of `return body;` it does log correctly.

I am kind of running in circles now I guess.

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the function `getItems` when calling `res.render` instead of executing the function, getting the output and assigning it to `items`.

```
res.render('home', {
       title: 'home',
       items: getItems // this is just a reference to "getItems" function.
   });
```

You need to execute the function `getItems` to get the actual data and render it in the view.

For flow control: You can wrap `getItems` in a promise and use `co-express` to `yield` the promise in a route handler.

Comment: That makes sense. I've had the same result when I do something like 'var getItems = request(porcess.env.API_URL, function(err, resp, body) { return body; });'.  I am I then not executing the function when I call the variable? The answer makes sense of corse cause I am just pointing to a variable but shouldn't this have worked?

Comment: You are making aync http requests, assigning it to a var won't work. You either need to get the data on the callback or wrap the request in a promise and yield it in the route handler.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It males much more sense now!